# Maven: dependency:unpack / how to override artifact dependency?

Tags: maven

I am working on a maven project, which depends on some artifact (named here "artifact1"), which is resolved using dependency:unpack:

pom.xml extract:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
    [...]
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>unpack</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>unpack</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>com.xxx.xxx</groupId>
                            <artifactId>artifact1</artifactId>
                            <version>100.1.1</version>
                            <type>zip</type>
                            [...]
                        </artifactItem>
                    </artifactItems>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
    [...]
    </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

"artifact1" has its own dependencies:

```
[INFO] +- com.xxx.xxx:artifact1:zip:100.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.xxx.xxx:artifact2:zip:100.1.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.xxx.xxx:xxx:artifact3:zip:100.1.1:compile
```

I am looking for a way to override version of "artifact3" (let us say to version 100.1.2) (without modifying anything on artifact1 project itself)

Expected result, running mvn dependency:tree with pom.xml here above and get dependency tree:

```
[INFO] +- com.xxx.xxx:artifact1:zip:100.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.xxx.xxx:artifact2:zip:100.1.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.xxx.xxx:xxx:artifact3:zip:100.1.2:compile
```

Do you know if there is any possibiliy to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't change a dependency (`artifact3`) that's declared in a project's (`artifact2`) POM on the fly. Can you describe the use case that makes this necessary?

Comment: Let's say artifact3:zip:100.1.2 is a kind of "hotfix" we received from an editor. The default way of deploying it is manual: first, install application and then, manual upload of this "hotfix". In order to avoid manual upload, I was looking for a way to override artifact1 dependencies and include it directly in the application package. Hope it's clear... If I undersand well, editor shall provide a version of artifact1 which depends on artifact3:zip:100.1.2 right?

Answer (score 0):

Basically Maven is a build tool, not a deployment tool. (It has a `deploy` phase but that's for deploying artifacts to a remote Maven repository, in addition to the local repository on the developer's local machine.)

There are plugins that support deploying of arbitrary files to arbitrary locations (indirectly):

- [Exec Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html): "*A Plugin for executing external programs.*"
- [GMavenPlus Plugin](https://groovy.github.io/GMavenPlus/index.html): "*a Maven plugin that allows you to integrate Groovy into your Maven projects.*"
- [Maven AntRun Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/): "*This plugin provides the ability to run Ant tasks from within Maven.*"

and one that supports deploying directly, but [its version 2.0.0](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/wagon-maven-plugin) is almost two years old and I experienced things not working with recent Maven versions. But, right now I see that [there's a 2.0.1 from just two days ago](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/wagon-maven-plugin):

- [Wagon Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/): "*Use this plugin to view and transfer resources between repositories using Maven Wagon.*"

  (Don't let "*between repositories*" confuse you. It supports arbitrary files and URLs.)

Comment: Hi Gerold, this is not exactly what I was looking for. I wanted to find a way to override this "n-level dependency" (if it makes sense to call it this way...) in the built package. I maybe badly expressed myself, to rephrase, the way to deploy our application is : 1/ mvn install (build a package), 2/ deploy the package with another tool 3/ Manually deploy the "hotfix". I was trying to include "artifact3" 100.1.2 inside the package built at step 1/, in order to avoid doing step 3/